# Mixed Content error when resource is HTTPS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, https, mixed-content

I'm developing a Chrome extension which enables the user to automatically login to a WordPress website. Almost everything is working, except the login part itself.

I'm loading the credentials from another server, then I create an iframe to **https**://example.com/wp-admin and fill in the username and password and submit it.

But when I load the URL in the src of the iframe, I get the following error:
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com/wp-admin/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

This error tells me that I'm using a http url, which I'm not. I'm 100% sure that I load it with a https url. The reason that I know for sure is that I debugged it using `console.log`, but even more evident is the iframe (in the Chrome debugger at the Inspect Element tab). 
It says: `<iframe id="autologin" src="https://example.com/wp-admin"></iframe>`.

So it **is** https, but I'm still getting the Mixed Content error.

How do I solve this?

This is the code that fails:

```
var loginUrl = 'https://example.com/wp-admin';
document.body.innerHTML += "<iframe id='autologin'></iframe>";
document.getElementById('autologin').src = loginUrl;
```

Comment: So maybe something is http inside of the page... link tag, script tage, img, etc. Or did it redirect to http instead of https?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that if I remove and then change the URL in the iframe src manually to https :// example.com/wp-admin it works perfectly (without the spaces ofcourse).

Comment: So something with the submission....

Comment: Why? I know for sure that the https url is entered as src

Comment: But the form submits.... Page does something.... Something in that something is http

Comment: I've added the javascript code that triggers the mixed content error.

Comment: If I go to https: // example.com/wp-admin manually, it stays at https. If I go to http: // example.com/wp-admin, it gets upgraded to https.

Comment: Beware: even if all the iframe's content is served with https as well, you might still have an issue with redirections. I had this issue with a RoundCube instance: I would access it with `https://domain/roundcube`, then The RC instance would redirect to `http://domain/roundcube/`, before redirecting to `https://domain/roundcube/`. It's a bit far-fetched, but when your browser complains about mixed content where there's none, check for unwanted redirections.